# How to remove value inside Array of Dictionary on Did DeSelect?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am populating my `tableView` with `OrderDetailsArray`. Then on `DidSelect` I am adding value to `reorderArray`.
How to remove value from array on tapping `DidDeSelect`?

My tableView delegate funcs:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let object = orderDetailsArray.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) as! NSDictionary

    let storeID = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: DefaultsKey.storeID.rawValue) as! Int
    let barcode = object["barcode"] as! String
    let mrp = object["mrp"] as! String
    let productDiscount = object["product_discount"] as! String

    reorderDictionary.setObject((storeID), forKey: "store_id" as NSCopying)
    reorderDictionary.setObject((barcode), forKey: "barcode" as NSCopying)
    reorderDictionary.setObject((mrp), forKey: "mrp" as NSCopying)
    reorderDictionary.setObject((productDiscount), forKey: "product_discount" as NSCopying)

    reorderArray.add(reorderDictionary)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! OrderHistoryProductDetailsTableViewCell
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    print(reorderArray)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! OrderHistoryProductDetailsTableViewCell
    let object = reorderArray.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) as! NSDictionary
    reorderArray.remove(object)
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    print(reorderArray)
}
```

reorderArray is `NSMutableArray()`

Comment: can you try placing the code  ` reorderArray.removeObjects(at: indexes)
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    print(reorderArray)` inside closure

Comment: It cannot be done because closure is returning value so if I am doing so then i am getting an error: variable used within its own initial value

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Foundation classes such as `NSMutableArray` or `NSDictionary` in Swift unless you have a good reason, but the simple answer is you can use `remove` to remove instances of an object from an `NSMutableArray` and you can easily find the relevant object from the index path:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! OrderHistoryProductDetailsTableViewCell
    let object = orderDetailsArray.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) as! NSDictionary
    reorderArray.add(object)
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    print(reorderArray)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let object = orderDetailsArray.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) as! NSDictionary
    reorderArray.remove(object)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! OrderHistoryProductDetailsTableViewCell
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    print(reorderArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0, you can try this, when used Array of Dictionary, you can do this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
 {
       let dicDetails = arrUserDetails[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary
       dicDetails.removeObject(forKey: "your_Key")

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Once**

```
 1.Create One more array globally and store indexpaths insted of reorderArray

OR

2.Apply this lines of code in TableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath:

if reorderArray.contains(reorderDictionary){
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}else{
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let object = orderDetailsArray.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) as! NSDictionary

     let storeID = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: DefaultsKey.storeID.rawValue) as! Int
     let barcode = object["barcode"] as! String
     let mrp = object["mrp"] as! String
     let productDiscount = object["product_discount"] as! String

     reorderDictionary.setObject((storeID), forKey: "store_id" as NSCopying)
     reorderDictionary.setObject((barcode), forKey: "barcode" as NSCopying)
     reorderDictionary.setObject((mrp), forKey: "mrp" as NSCopying)
     reorderDictionary.setObject((productDiscount), forKey: "product_discount" as NSCopying)
     let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! OrderHistoryProductDetailsTableViewCell
     if reorderArray.contains(reorderDictionary){
        reorderArray.remove(reorderDictionary)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
     }else{
      reorderArray.add(reorderDictionary)
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
     }

    print(reorderArray)
}
```